# PHP Statements using exec

Tags: php

I'm trying to use if statements to determine if it's 64 or 32 bit where to look for.

```
 if (isset($_POST['Scratch'])) {
    exec(' ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Scratch 2\Scratch 2.exe")');
} else if(isset($_POST['Scratch']))  {
    exec(' ("C:\Program Files\Scratch 2\Scratch 2.exe")');
}
```

but the first line works but when it goes to use the else if it does not work, is this going to work?

Answer (score 0):

In 32-bit systems PHP_INT_SIZE should be 4, for 64-bit it should be 8

```
<?php
switch(PHP_INT_SIZE) {
    case 4:
        echo '32-bit version of PHP';
        break;
    case 8:
        echo '64-bit version of PHP';
        break;
    default:
        echo 'PHP_INT_SIZE is ' . PHP_INT_SIZE;
}
?>
```

More details about PHP_INT_SIZE http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php

Comment: ok and without sounding too silly cause i'm still learning instead of the echo i just run my exec command